# ASP NET -Bootstrap does not work well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im learning some twitter bootstrap concepts. But that snippet does not show the result I expect. The problem is inside the brand div. The brand class shows a title, but in my browser does not look like base webpage.

is there something wrong here?

**EDIT1**
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TVS.WebForm1" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"> 
    <a href="#" class="brand">Responsive</a>
        <br />
    <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things. Your css files are linked in the wrong order and you have both the normal and minified version of the same files linked in your html. You only need one of those, typically the regular one during development and the minified one in production. Same with the javascript files, you only need one of those and they should go at the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag.

Comment: I've fix that problem, but the problem is still here.